after putting wireless card in monitor mode, I cannot get available wifi
I am aware that in monitor mode, you might be get disconnected from the internet. You wont be able to access to the internet inside the monitor mode because network manager stops. so I restart it:
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager

then I put the wlan0 (my wireless card name) in managed mode
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

I run iwconfig and see that wlan0 is in managed mode:
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=-2147483648 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

but i still cannot see the wifi connections. if i restart the machine, I get back normal settings but I dont want to restart everytime I work on monitor mode

NetworkManager needs to be restarted after NIC is set to managed mode, not before, therefore:
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager



You wont be able to access to the internet inside the monitor mode because network manager stops

Your understanding is back to front. Network Manager stops because you have switched the wireless card away from managed mode to monitor mode. The two modes are exclusive: you can have one or the other but not both at the same time.
